# Import system properties to maven plugin's Spring context

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have in-house developed maven plugin(lets call it **A**) which uses spring IOC container and a maven project(call it **B**) that uses this plugin.

I want to specify particular plugin configuration in B's pom.xml, so this property will be accessed in plugin's spring context

I expect something like this,
pom.xml (project **B**)

```
<plugin>
...
 <configuration>
    <dummyproperty>dummy_value</dummyproperty>
 </configuration>
...
</plugin>
```

Spring_context.xml (project **A** - plugin)

```
<bean class="com.blabla.SomeClass">
 <property name="someBeanProperty" value="${dummyproperty}" />
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
```

I've tried various approaches with using plugin configuration, , additional property files, but placeholders in spring context not get populated with real values.
Asking for your help with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't you use Plexus, Maven's built-in IOC container, instead of Spring? Plexus integrates very tightly with Maven. You can access the system property just by putting `@parameter expression="${dummyproperty}"` in the javadoc of the setter of the attribute.

Comment: @abhin4v: Agreed. There is even a plexus-spring "bridge" allowing to reuse spring beans in Plexus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented exactly the same kind of plugin. The solution was to have a Properties member in the plugin mojo, which is then configured using the usual `<cofiguration>` section.

The plugin mojo was responsible for loading the spring XML and creating the app context. Before using the app context, the mojo instantiated a PropertiesPlaceHolderConfigurer, setting the properties to the Properties instance configured in the mojo.

For convenience, I also had a Properties instance where the values were ignored, and instead fetched from the project. This allows properties to be conveniently set in the spring config with the same values as they were in the maven project.